# pass to lists from AsyncTask to activity

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, android-activity

i have in my activity two methods getListIDs  AND getNamesIDs  so in the AsycTask class there is some process in background to get from database Tow Lists , the first list Supposed to send it's result to getListIDs() and activity class , and second list also to getNamesIDS()

My Q is : how to return those two lists from Async class two used into Two methods in activity class ?

my code in activity class :

```
    public List<Student> getListIDs() {

    return list; // return full list 

    public List<Student> getNamesIDs() {

    return list; // return full list
```

my code in AsyncTask class :

```
  public class Hashom extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

static Activity mActivity;
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

public Hashom(Activity activity, ProgressDialog progressDialog) {
    super();
    this.progressDialog = progressDialog;
    this.mActivity = activity;

}

final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.sams.com";
final String URL = "http://88.198.82.92:8080/sams1/services/listActivityWS?WSDL"; 
                                                                                     localhost
final String METHOD_NAME = "getCurrentClassList";
final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.sams.com/getCurrentClassList";

final String NAMESPACE2 = "http://ws.sams.com";
final String URL2 = "http://88.198.82.92:8080/sams1/services/listActivityWS?WSDL"; // usint
                                                                                    // localhost
final String METHOD_NAME2 = "getStudentId";
final String SOAP_ACTION2 = "http://ws.sams.com/getStudentId";

final String NAMESPACE3 = "http://ws.sams.com";
final String URL3 = "http://88.198.82.92:8080/sams1/services/listActivityWS?WSDL"; // usint
                                                                                    // localhost
final String METHOD_NAME3 = "getCourseName";
final String SOAP_ACTION3 = "http://ws.sams.com/getCourseName";

final String NAMESPACE4 = "http://ws.sams.com";
final String URL4 = "http://88.198.82.92:8080/sams1/services/listActivityWS?WSDL"; // usint
                                                                                    // localhost
final String METHOD_NAME4 = "getClassId";
final String SOAP_ACTION4 = "http://ws.sams.com/getClassId";

List<Student> StudentIdList = new ArrayList<Student>();
List<Student> StudentNamesList = new ArrayList<Student>();

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {




        SoapObject request3 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
        HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport3 = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
        PropertyInfo pi3 = new PropertyInfo();
        pi3.setName("TID");
        pi3.setValue(1);
        pi3.setType(Integer.class);
        request3.addProperty(pi3);

        SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope3 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                SoapEnvelope.VER11);
        envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

        androidHttpTransport3.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope3);

        KvmSerializable result = (KvmSerializable) envelope3.bodyIn;

        String str = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            str = ((String) result.getProperty(i).toString());

            Student hesham = new Student(str);
            StudentNamesList.add(hesham);

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {

    }

    // ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    SoapObject request4 = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE2, METHOD_NAME2);
    PropertyInfo pi4 = new PropertyInfo();
    pi4.setName("TID");
    pi4.setValue(1);
    pi4.setType(Integer.class);
    request.addProperty(pi4);
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope4 = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
            SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request4);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport4 = new HttpTransportSE(URL2);

    try {

        androidHttpTransport4.call(SOAP_ACTION2, envelope4);

        KvmSerializable result = (KvmSerializable) envelope.bodyIn;

        String str = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < result.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
            str = ((String) result.getProperty(i).toString());

            Student hesham = new Student(str);

            StudentIdList.add(hesham);

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
    }
    return "hh";  // i want here to return two lists (StudentIdList) and StudentNamesList and calling the reult into activity class 
}





@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ListActivity1.class);
    mActivity.startActivity(intent);

    progressDialog.dismiss();
}

  }
```

Comment: And... the question is?

Comment: the qustion how to return two lists to methods in activity

Comment: am i sleepy or its hard to understand what you are trying to say ...

Comment: in doInBackground the result will be two lists OK ? i want these two reslut move into activity class to work with them and get it's values .

Comment: I see that you start a new activity in onPostExecute() now the question is, is the activity you start the activity you want to show the lists in?

Comment: Then you have to send the data to that activity. In onPostExecute, you have to putExtra(Key, List1) in the INtent (INtent.putExtra("List1", List)) and the same for the other.

Comment: The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Student>)

Answer (score 0):

Your onPostExecute() should look something like this:

```
public void onPostExecute()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(mActivity, ListActivity1.class);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("STUDENT_IDS", StudentIdList);
    intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("STUDENT_NAMES", StudentNamesList); 
    mActivity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

of course that means that your Student Class must be Parcelable. And the List you are using should be ArrayList

Plus your way of writing variable names is against standard Java conventions. Only classes start with an uppercase letter (it should be ArrayList studentNames)

in your new actvityity

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
if(b != null)
{
    list1 = b.getParcelableArrayList<Student>("STUDENT_IDS");
    list2 = b.getParcelableArrayList<Student>("STUDENT_NAMES);
}
```

again above is not tested but should work with a couple of minor bug fixes. Look into [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getParcelableArrayList%28java.lang.String%29) and [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putParcelableArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String,%20java.util.ArrayList%3C?%20extends%20android.os.Parcelable%3E%29)

Comment: The method putExtra(String, boolean) in the type Intent is not applicable for the arguments (String, List<Student>)

Comment: now in activity class how to get list from intent ,  Intent intent = getIntent();
     Serializable mylist = intent.getSerializableExtra("StudentIdList"); // how to extract mylist  to return it as acutal list

Comment: did this help you with your problem?